# Eclipse image assets not being found?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, image, grails

I'm having some trouble with assets in  eclipse, how to I access them in javascript?

this is my project's structure:

[image]

Already tried "/assets/images/spinner.gif", "/assets/spinner.gif" and "/images/spinner.gif"
What am I missing?

thansk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loading.src = "/YOURAPPNAME/assets/spinner.gif";
```

Although I prefer to have that gif in a div a then only show/hide that div and don't mess with paths.

```
$("#spinner").hide();
$("#spinner").show();
```